# Run my own HTTP fast-browsing proxy a la Opera Mini?

Tags: proxy, web, http

Opera Mini is a great browser that works well on feature phones and iPhones. Unlike most browsers, it uses Opera's servers to transcode every page you browse to into a small, easy-to-render chunk that's sent to Opera Mini.

What's a simple way for me to set up something similar on a very fast VPS out there so I can browse more comfortably on a 10KBps connection? I have no idea where to start, but I'm most comfortable in the NodeJS world.

Comment: you could start with looking at squid which is very powerfull, but I think you'll never find something that also adapt a web page to the screen of a mobile phone.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a forwarding, non-caching, HTTP proxy server targeted for traffic optimization, which is what Opera uses on their servers. There are two open source proxies available for you to install on your own server:

1. [Ziproxy](http://ziproxy.sourceforge.net/index.html), which is already available in the repositories for some distributions.
2. [RabbIT](http://www.khelekore.org/rabbit/).

Comment: +1 I'd be interested in reading how much this really saves an average user.  You can't squeeze a stone that much, and browser caching will make a lot of the benefits theoretical.

Comment: @goldilocks I have an instance of Opera 12 open for about 10 hours. Upon clicking its icon it tells me I saved 1,2 GB on this session, which is 50% of all HTTP traffic. On my limited 3G plan the difference is really noticeable, mainly in websites full of images, of course.

Comment: 50% is a lot.  I did read "up to 90%", which makes sense for an all text page.  You cannot significantly compress .jpg and .png files, though, unless you reduce the size/resolution/quality.  Which online often won't matter much, particularly on a phone. Social network-y stuff can contain ridiculously high-res images even after the platform itself has reduced them somewhat.

Comment: @goldilocks Yes, it comes at a cost - Opera recompresses images as WEBP. It really isn't very noticeable, though, unless you are viewing some high resolution pictures as in photo-sharing websites, like you mentioned. Opera also offers a "reload image in original quality" right-click option, which the OP won't be able to replicate. Also, for people with high-speed Internet access, it will just increase the latency.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a terminal, I would recommend installing [Browsh](https://www.brow.sh) browser on your VPS and connect to it using [Mosh](https://mosh.org/) SSH client, which keeps connection alive in case of lost connectivity. This solution gives you much data savings.